# What is the "emergency crush core"?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, design

In his  [tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/878334920141135872) Elon Musk said: "Rocket is extra toasty and hit the deck hard (used almost all of the emergency crush core)"

What is he talking about?

Comment: related: [Why were three engines used for the F9 1st stage landing burn (BulgariaSat-1)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22079/12102)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The landing legs have a honey-comb filler that can compress to absorb significant energy of a hot landing.

[image]

<sup>([Source: @SpaceX](https://twitter.com/spacex/status/738453366649430016))</sup>

Comment: Additional crush core information from a previous landing (Thaicom-8) can be found [in this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15532/12102).

Comment: Hah, I was about to ask if SpaceX was hand drafting technical diagrams, but those are from Apollo.

Comment: What if the distribution of forces between legs is uneven? Do you end up with uneven leg lengths, or does this imply that there is secondary (less robust) suspension to keep things balanced?

Comment: From the video footage after landing it looked to me like the legs did indeed end up with uneven lengths.

Comment: I'm assuming that by 'hot', you mean fast? Might want to clarify this.

Comment: This is the same method the LEM during Apollo used.  I have pictures of a mothballed one from the Cradle of Aviation Museum (I believe it was set to be Apollo 18 LEM) if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 8):

The legs are designed to bounce and take some impact on landing. For further absorption of shock they include non-reusable crush cores, that deform and absorb the energy but cannot bounce back.

They are made replaceable and it is preferable to use them up than to have the stage hit the deck.